# JQuery: addClass() is not working despite correct selection

Tags: jquery, dimple.js

I have been looking at this for too long, and imagine this is something simple, but can't seem to find the solution.

I have added a bar chart to a div using dimple.js, and I am trying to change the class of one of the bars based on a dropdown selection.

I have a variable that holds the selection, and it works correctly.  I can log the value in the console, and it shows the correct object.  However the class never gets added.

Any help would be appreciated.

```
  var barClass = 'rect.dimple-' + selectedHospital.split(' ').join('-').toLowerCase();
  console.log($(barClass));
  $(barClass).addClass('addedClass')
```

result of the console.log();

```
[rect#dimple-all--hospital-1--, prevObject: n.fn.init(1), context: document, selector: "rect.dimple-hospital-1"]
```

Comment: does it appear in the logs if you are checking the console.log($(barClass).addClass('addedClass')); ?
and why are you adding a class "rect.dimple" and returning in the logs an id "rect#dimple"?

Comment: it still shows in the log if i add the .addClass('addedClass'), but without the new class.  When i inspect the element on the browser, the id is rect#dimple-all--hospital-1--, but I am trying to select it by class.

Comment: So the element has an id and a class?

Comment: Yes, it has an ID and many classes

Comment: As an update, if i add $(barClass).hide() the bar disappears, so I know that the code is referencing the correct element.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this by changing to using JQuery v3.2.1 (was using v2.1.1).  From what I have read, prior to this version classes cannot be added to elements within an SVG.